# disabled autoplay in iframe with html5 or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to disable autoplay in iframe with javascript/jquery or attribute HTML5, I have disabled autoplay in iframe.

code :

```
  <div id="vds" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin-top: -100px;">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" {% if profil.pageAccueil %}{%if profil.pageAccueil.video!=""%}src="{{profil.pageAccueil.video}}"{%else%} {{pageAccueil.video}} {%endif%}{%endif%}></iframe>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? please have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I edit my question and I make my code

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
<div id="vds" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin-top: -100px;">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" {% if profil.pageAccueil %}{%if profil.pageAccueil.video!=""%}src="{{profil.pageAccueil.video}}"{%else%} {{pageAccueil.video}} {%endif%}{%endif%}></iframe>
</div>
```

with

```
  <div id="vds" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="margin-top: -100px;"> 
      <video class="class="embed-responsive-item"" width="600" height="400">
          <source {% if profil.pageAccueil %}{%if profil.pageAccueil.video!=""%}src="{{profil.pageAccueil.video}}"{%else%} {{pageAccueil.video}} {%endif%}{%endif%}> type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
```

Comment: try to use video tag instead iframe.

Comment: with video tag i have this problem https://user.oc-static.com/upload/2017/04/14/14921486996416_q.png